# com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider Showed in Struts2 Text field value

Tags: jsp, parameters, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

My JSP is getting the parameters from the URL and it is working fine. But if there is no parameters in the URL, the text field's value shows
`com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider`.

Like when the URL is `login.jsp?user=USER1`, it outputs `USER1`. But if it's `login.jsp` it shows `com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

String user = request.getParameter("user");
        if(user == null) user = "";

<c:set var="user"><%=user%></html:set>
<c:textfield id="user" name="user" value='%{#user}'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use scriptlets and JSTL tags to get a request parameter.

Instead you can access parameters via OGNL. Use naming prefix for taglibs.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<s:textfield id="user" name="user" value="%{#parameters.user}"/>
```